What's the recommended way to allow both programmatic AND user standard input to a Process in a console app?
Not a duplicate of this question. OP seems to be trying to retrieve output and present it in a GUI. This question is about recieving multiple simultaneous inputs from both the program and from a TUI.
I want to allow both my program, and the user interacting with the console, to give standard input to a process in C#.
As an example (NB: Simplified example, not actual use case), take a function that wraps fzf:
    public static string RunFzf(IEnumerable<string> opts)
    {
        Process p = new()
        {
            StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                RedirectStandardInput = true,
                FileName = "bash",
                Arguments = "-c fzf"
            }
        };

        p.Start();
        foreach (string opt in opts)
        {
            p.StandardInput.WriteLine(opt);
        }

        string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        p.WaitForExit();
        return output;
    }

If I pass RedirectStandardInput = true, the foreach loop can populate the values that will be available to find through, however the user is unable to input anything through the shell, making the function useless.
On the contrary, leaving RedirectStandardInput as false causes an InvalidOperationException when trying to write to the standard input, as "StandardIn has not been redirected".
What I've Tried
I've tried setting p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = false after the end of the loop, however this makes no change - the user still cannot input via the shell.
My next idea would be to listen to key presses from the console, and call p.StandardInput.Write for each key press recieved, however this seems convoluted and like it might interfere with some of the user's expected behaviour.
Is there a recommended way to allow a process to recieve standard input both programmatically from code, and from the user via their shell?

Not a duplicate of this question...: Did you read the answer or just the original post? Did you implement/test the code in the answer?
